# Things to do with ISR

Tags: interrupts, firmware

I have an ISR that increments a counter every 5ms if the switch is pressed.

If the counter becomes 200 then do Reset. I plan to add more functions to be called from the counter value.

After a few encounters with ISRs, I have got the expert advice from this site to keep ISR short.

Then how should I keep the ISR properly or near to perfection.

Is it about keeping flags?

I trust calling ISR that do long routines is a bad architecture. But then how can I call long routines from the value of flags in ISR if it is kept in another source files other than `main.c`?

Answer (score 3):

Allowing access to variables between source files is done using the **extern** keyword, for example in header file declaring a variable. If it's all in one file you can use a global variable.

When you want an ISR to be able to change the variable (such as a flag) and have another routine recognize the change (perhaps by polling the flags periodically between doing other stuff), it's best to use the **volatile** keyword, which prevents the variable from being optimized out of the code (since otherwise the compiler does not see how it could change).

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-share-a-variable-between-source-files-in-c-with-extern-but-how  for more info on **extern**

And: http://www.barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/C-Volatile-Keyword for more info on **volatile**

Comment: Thank you @Spehro Pefhany.But  if it's not in same file.What should be done to make the flag change visible in the other source file.

Comment: Declare the variable as extern in a header file, include that header file in each source file that needs to access it. Define it in one file. That has nothing to do with ISRs, it's just C programming. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-share-a-variable-between-source-files-in-c-with-extern-but-how

Comment: If it's changed in an ISR, then add the volatile keyword. http://www.barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/C-Volatile-Keyword